# Is there a SwiftUI way of making text superscript or subscript?

Tags: swiftui

I know an offset can be applied like `Text("TM").offset(x:0, y:7)` but is there a different or better way to create a bit of super or subscript text in SwiftUI?

Comment: `.baselineOffset` would probably be more appropriate than `.offset`.

Comment: You can still do it the old way with a UILabel and NSAttributedString if you use UIViewRepresentable to wrap your label.  I imagine that Text will one day eventually either support NSAttributedString or maybe a fancy Swift function builder based successor.

Comment: @robmayoff Is ```.baselineOffset``` as buggy for you as it is for me? It's pretty much useless for values under 13 in both simulator and physical device.

Comment: @R.J. Can you post a code example? `.baselineOffset` works for me. Also, are you mainly after symbols like TM, or powers/exponents, etc? Just wondering since there are different approaches for both.

Comment: @Austin Mostly symbols. What would differ for exponents or powers? I noticed after I saw your answer that I had ```.font(.footnote)``` after ```.baselineOffset```. I suppose that could have been part of my problem. I keep forgetting order is very important.

Comment: @R.J. Sorry, at the time I didn't realize Unicode had so many superscript/subscript symbols, so I was going to suggest the `.baselineOffset` approach for them (exponents, etc.). But it turns out there are a ton, I found this [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) while searching. Happy it worked for you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a generic way using `.baselineOffset`:

```swift
Text("Company")
    .font(.callout)
+ Text("TM")
    .font(.system(size: 8.0))
    .baselineOffset(6.0)
```

I'm sure there's a way to get the correct offset dynamically using `CTFont`, but I think it may be a pain. A sloppy way would be to wrap the Text View(s)? in a GeometryReader, and use the height to try and position it so it looks good.

You can also use Unicode for some symbols (like ™):

```swift
Text("Company\u{2122}")
```

Comment: For characters like superscript numbers in license terms blurbs and so forth, the unicode method is the way to go.

Comment: Unicode is the choice, not baselineOffset, because the latter does not supporting dynamic font.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode is the only best choice for this, and don't use baselineOffset or other swiftui views:

```swift
Text("Do you want a new model iPhone\u{00AE} from Apple\u{2122}? Do you listen to Apple Music\u{2120} or Spotify℠?")
Text("1 meter^3 is 1 m\u{00B3} or 1 m³")
Text("the power (666*10⁻¹⁹)")
```

And you can find unicodes or any symbols on websites or [unicode-table.com](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/) .

Comment: Why _"don't use baselineOffset"_?

Comment: Because when you change the font size of your device, it will not adjust automatically. Try it.

Comment: And [here](https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/blocks/superscripts-and-subscripts/) is the link for superscripts and subscripts in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

#### Think Different

Sometimes you may end up with some limitation that prevents you from applying SwiftUI modifiers. (like when the `CustomUIKit` is close source and you can't separate a `Text` into two different `Text` + `Text` or using a `HStack`)

It may be worth mentioning that you can use some characters natively supported by all Apple platforms.

For example, these are some small capital letters to be used as subscript:

```
A ᴀ
B ʙ
C ᴄ
D ᴅ
```

These are to be used as superscripts:

```
A ᴬ
B ᴮ
TM ™ //  Here is what you mentioned in the question
```

All of these can be found in the `Character Viewr` that you can find under the menu `Edit` -> `Emoji & Symbols` (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

[image: Character viewr]

Answer (score 0):

**If using SwiftUI**

This pattern is more verbose but allows for programmatic superscript of non Text types (like Image).

```
HStack {
    Text("Company")
    VStack {
        Text("TM")
            .font(.system(size: 8))
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

Here is an example of using it programmatically:

```
struct SampleInput: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var superScript: AnyView
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var sampleInput: [SampleInput]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(sampleInput) {input in
                HStack {
                    Text(input.text)
                    VStack {
                        input.superScript
                            .font(.system(size: 8))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To populate the preview:

```
struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(sampleInput: [
            SampleInput(text: "Company", superScript: AnyView(Text("TM"))),
            SampleInput(text: "Company", superScript: AnyView(Image(systemName: "info.circle")))
        ])
    }
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

May not suite everybody and not true subscript in context of accessibility font scales, but combining HStack with .bottom alignment and .baselineOffset worked for me - e.g. something like:

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    Text("subscript")
       .font(.system(size: 10.0))
       .baselineOffset(4.0)
       .padding(0)
    Text("normal")
       .font(.title2)
       .padding(0)
}.padding(0)
```